# Ant Design Select. Don't clear search value after blur

Tags: antd

I don't want the search value to be cleared on blur. How can I achieve this?

```js
<Select
  style={{ width: "240px" }}
  placeholder="Search..."
  showSearch={true}
/>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-5o5fx?file=/index.js)

Comment: why you use `Select` for this?

Comment: Because reimplementing all features of select using dropdown + input is overhead. For example, dropdown doesn't support scroll, dropdown supports only `Menu` overlay etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a try with [AutoComplete](https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/#components-auto-complete-demo-certain-category).

As the documentation says

#### When To Use

- When you need an input box instead of a selector.
- When you need input suggestions or helping text.

##### The differences with `Select` are:

- AutoComplete is an input box with text hints, and users can type freely. The keyword is **aiding input**.
- Select is selecting among given choices. The keyword is **select**.

[example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/non-case-sensitive-autocomplete-antd-4-17-0-alpha-0-forked-kwhlo)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is a possible solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thank you! I was struggling with Select while I actually needed AutoComplete